# JSON Parsing in Bash

Tags: json, bash

I have a json file which needs to be restructured. 
The following is the code.

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))
    #echo "[$COUNT]"
    [ $COUNT -lt 5 ] && continue
    sj=`echo $line | jq ._source`
    index=`echo $line | jq ._index | tr -d '"'`
    itype=`echo $line | jq ._type| tr -d '"'`
    echo '{ "index" : { "_index" :"'$index'","_type":"'$itype'"}}' >> bulk_result.bulk
    echo $sj >> bulk_result.bulk
#echo "$COUNT lines processed from file $1"
done < "$1"
echo "$COUNT lines processed from file $1"
```

Basically, the program is reading  a json record for example,

```
{"_index":"index1","_type":"rm","_id":"AVPkyS9w","_score":1,"_source":{"timestamp":"2016-04-05T05:00:00","token":"8eb38d14","tag":"logs.rm","message":"CouchbaseConnectSuccess,bucket=srmobjects","logsource":"rm.log","RM_pw":"","component":"rm-01-NFR","RM_un":"","timeEpochMs":1459832400.248,"RM_bucket":"srmobjects","RM_eventName":"CouchbaseConnectSuccess"}}
```

and converting it to the following

```
{ "index" : { "_index" :"index1","_type":"rm"}}
{ "RM_eventName": "FcgiClose", "timeEpochMs": 1459832435.293, "component": "rm-04-NFR", "logsource": "rm.log", "message": "FcgiClose,requestIndex=0", "tag": "logs.rm", "timestamp": "2016-04-05T05:00:35" }
```

The file size is about 4Gb . The code is taking a lot of time (in hours) in processing it.  Is there an efficient way to make this faster ?

Comment: Do you not have  a scripting language that isn't painful to work in?

Comment: why fire a python interpreter, when you can write a one liner :P

Answer (score 15):

Bash is not well-suited for transforming JSON. But `jq` is. But calling `jq` 3 times for each line of input is certainly going to be slow.

There are several other issues too with the script. The `` `...` `` syntax is obsolete in favor of `$(...)`; the counting can be simplified, or even better, eliminated using `tail -n +5`; and the repeated `bulk_result.bulk` would be good to put in a variable.

But none of that matters much, as it seems the entire script can be replaced with a single line:

```
tail -n +5 "$1" | jq -rc '{index: {_index: ._index, _type: ._type}}, ._source'
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the entire loop, instead of redirecting individual commands. Instead of opening and closing the file for each iteration of the loop, you can have the file open for the duration of the loop. This is much more efficient.

Consider writing diagnostic information to stderr.

From:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    …
    #echo "[$COUNT]"
    …
    echo '{ "index" : { "_index" :"'$index'","_type":"'$itype'"}}' >> bulk_result.bulk
    echo $sj >> bulk_result.bulk
    #echo "$COUNT lines processed from file $1"
done < "$1"
```

To:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    …
    #echo "[$COUNT]" >&2
    …
    echo '{ "index" : { "_index" :"'$index'","_type":"'$itype'"}}'
    echo $sj
    #echo "$COUNT lines processed from file $1" >&2
done < "$1" >> bulk_result.bulk
```

(Yes, I know those `echo`s are commented out.)

Always quote your variables unless you know you want them to be unquoted:

```
sj=$(echo "$line" | jq ._source)
index=$(echo "$line" | jq ._index | tr -d '"')
itype=$(echo "$line" | jq ._type| tr -d '"')
echo '{ "index" : { "_index" :"'"$index"'","_type":"'"$itype"'"}}'
echo "$sj"
```

Better yet, when dealing with complex quoting for obtaining output in a format, consider using `printf`:

```
echo '{ "index" : { "_index" :"'$index'","_type":"'$itype'"}}'
echo "$sj"
```

Becomes:

```
printf '{ "index" : { "_index" :"%s","_type":"%s"}}\n%s\n' "$index" "$itype" "$sj"
```

Since this is bash, and you have already used `[[`, favour it over `[`:

```
[[ $COUNT -lt 5 ]] && continue
```

When dealing strictly with integers, you can force [an arithmetic context](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) with `(( … ))`:

```
(( COUNT < 5 )) && continue
```

Of course, none of this matters much. ;)